# What's the better way to choose pivot for quicksort?

Tags: pivot, quicksort

Some people told me there were a list of optimized pivot for Quicksort, but I searched on the net and I didn't found it.
So this list contain a lot of prime number, but also many others (nowadays we aren't able to explain why this pivot are the best).
Then if u know Something about it or have some documentation, I'm interested.
If you know another way to optimize the quicksort I'm interested too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to select a universally optimal pivot without inspecting the data. If the data is always random, any pivot strategy is as good as another. If data has specific tendencies, for example to already be sorted-ish, then taking those tendencies into consideration will give you a better chance of choosing a better pivot. A median between several elements gives you better chances your pivot is good, but selecting which elements will be your candidate pivots comes with the same disclaimer as above.

Answer (score 0):

One sort that uses a list of numbers is shell short, where the numbers are used for the "gaps":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences

For quicksort, using median of 3 will help, median of 9 helps a bit more, and median of medians guarantees worst case O(n log(n)) time complexity, but involves a large constant factor that in most cases, results in a slower overall quicksort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Introsort with a reasonable pivot choice (random, median of 3, 9, ...), that switches to heapsort if the level of recursion becomes too deep is a common choice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

Answer (score 0):

There's no better way to pick a pivot than to pick the middle element of the list as our pivot.

Why?

The ideal way to find a pivot for a list of numbers is to find a pivot randomly. However, the additional randomization process will take additional time complexity or space complexity.

What if we just select the first element as a pivot and say that's somehow "random" for the list?
If the list is already sorted and select the first element as a pivot, then the algorithm will generate to have a time complexity of O(n^2) instead of our average time O(nlogn).

Therefore, in order to guarantee no additional time complexity is used and to not degenerate our algorithm. The quickest, easiest, and most common fix is to use the middle element of the list as our pivot. If so, we could guarantee that our algorithm is O(nlogn). It will be extremely difficult for our algorithm at this point to degenerate, unless it is ordered purposely in a way so as to degenerate it.